# How can I use Ctrl+D to bookmark a page after installed vimperator

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I'v installed the vimperator, but I found that the shortcut **Ctrl+D** cannot bookmark the page anymore.
I have searched long time, but still cannot found the solution.
Anyone knows that?
Thanks.

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

```
noremap <C-d> :dialog addbookmark<CR>
```

Well, I need read more help file. :)

Answer (score 2):

For bookmarking, use 'a', optionally edit the url and bookmark title in the status bar, then return.

Comment: This method can saved the bookmark in `Bookmarks Menu`. How can I saved the bookmark in specific folders?